# find the latest file that was modified within last minute in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a list of files in a particular directory as shown below:

```
david@host:~/jobs/process/workspace/files$ ls -lrth
total 68K
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 7.8K Oct  1 11:10 golden_proc.init.1569953435497
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 7.7K Oct  2 12:11 golden_proc.init.1570043494149
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 7.7K Oct  2 20:15 golden_proc.init.1570072510929
```

Each file name ends with timestamp in it. Now I need to find one latest file which was modified or created just a minute back in ansible.

- If there is no file like that then return successfully from the ansible by logging "cannot find any file" if this is possible to do.
- If there is a file like that then copy that file to "/tmp" folder.
- If there are multiple files generated or modified in the last minute then use the latest one.

Is this possible to do in ansible? I saw there is a find module in ansible but not sure how can I make above things work using that module?

```
---
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
      - name: find the latest file
        find: paths=/var/lib/jobs/workspace/process/files
              file_type=file
              age=-{{ time_window }}m
              age_stamp=mtime
        register: files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely something possible, you are even close from the solution.

As you might have seen it doing a `debug` of your `find` already, the return of it contains a list of `files`, this list would just be empty if you have no file.

So it become pretty easy to see when the list is empty with Jinja

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ files.files if files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'
```

This syntax is using an [inline `if`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#if-expression) as well as a [`count` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#length).

Regarding the fact that you want the most recent file now, you can also use a set of Jinja filers: the [filter `sort`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#sort) will help you sort the files by modification time, and the [filter `first`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#first) will help you get only the first element of you list.

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path }}'
```

Now you just need to combine both in one long Jinja expression:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path if files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'
```

In order to copy the file, you will need one extra Jinja filter that is specific to Ansible and that is [`basename`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), in order to get the name of the file out of its full path

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path | basename if files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'
```

But you will also need the [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) statement so your copy will be skipped if there is no matching file:

```
- name: Copy file, if found                 
  copy:
    src: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path }}'
    dest: '/tmp/{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path | basename }}'
  when: files.files|count > 0
```

A full working playbook for you to test:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: locale

  vars:
    var_files:
      - { 'name': 'a', 'time': 86400 }
      - { 'name': 'b', 'time': 30 }
      - { 'name': 'c', 'time': 20 }

  tasks:
    - name: creating a bunch of matching files
      file:
        path: '/data/{{ item.name }}'
        state: touch
      with_items: '{{ var_files }}'

    - name: aging those files
      file:
        path: '/data/{{ item.name }}'
        modification_time: '{{ "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" | strftime( ( ansible_date_time.epoch | int ) - item.time ) }}'
      with_items: '{{ var_files }}'

    - name: find the latest file
      find: paths=/data
        file_type=file
        age=-1m
        age_stamp=mtime
      register: files

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path if files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'

    - name: Copy file, if found
      copy:
        src: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path }}'
        dest: '/tmp/{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path | basename }}'
      when: files.files|count > 0

    - name: removing files to test the behaviour with no matching files
      file:
        path: '/data/{{ item.name }}'
        state: absent
      with_items: '{{ var_files }}'

    - name: find the latest file
      find: paths=/data
        file_type=file
        age=-1m
        age_stamp=mtime
      register: files

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path if files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'    

    - name: Copy file, if found                 
      copy:
        src: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path }}'
        dest: '/tmp/{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path | basename }}'
      when: files.files|count > 0
```

And the corresponding output of that playbook

```
PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [creating a bunch of matching files] *******************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'a', 'time': 86400})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'b', 'time': 30})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'c', 'time': 20})

TASK [aging those files] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'a', 'time': 86400})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'b', 'time': 30})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'c', 'time': 20})

TASK [find the latest file] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/data/c"
}

TASK [Copy file, if found] **********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [removing files to test the behaviour with no matching files] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'a', 'time': 86400})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'b', 'time': 30})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'c', 'time': 20})

TASK [find the latest file] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "cannot find any file"
}

TASK [Copy file, if found] **********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=9    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Thanks for detailed explanation. So basically `msg` variable will have the latest file details right? So can we copy this latest file to /tmp folder as well? Is there any way to pass the latest file name to the next step of ansible script which will be responsible to copy the file to /tmp folder?

Comment: @flash sure, you have it now

Comment: why do we have `10000000w` in the above script? For my use case, I need the latest file which generated or modified within 1minute window right? so it should be `age=-1m`? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @flash because, from you question, that did not seems to be your issue, and there was no need to add over complexity to the file creating steps I was just adding for the sake of having a complete example. But if that is really what you want, there is the updated answer.

Comment: Yes makes sense. I thought maybe you forgot to correct that. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I have one more question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58275627/how-to-skip-all-other-plays-in-ansible-playbook-if-some-condition-is-not-met) since past few days and I am not able to figure out the best way to do it yes? Wanted to see if you can help me out.