# How to skip all other plays in ansible playbook if some condition is not met?

Tags: linux, ansible

I have multiple plays in below playbook. I want to ignore all other plays if some condition is not met.

So for below example - If I cannot find any new file in `Play1` then I don't want to execute `Play2` and `Play3` at all (it should skip it). How can I do that?

I have `end_play` in Play1 but it only skips `Play1` and it still executes `Play2` and `Play3`

```
---
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
      - name: find the latest file
        find: paths=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/files
              file_type=file
              age=-1m
              age_stamp=mtime
        register: files

      - meta: end_play
        when: files.files|count == 0

      - name: Copy file, if found
        copy:
          src: "some stuff here"
          dest: "some other stuff here"
        when: files.files|count > 0

- name: Play 2
  hosts: all
  serial: 5
  tasks:
      - name: copy latest file
        copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data01/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

      - name: copy latest file
        copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data02/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

- name: Play 3
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
      - name: execute command
        shell: ./data_init --init_file ./goldy.init.qa
        args:
          chdir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/data_init/
```

**Update:**

So block module solution doesn't work looks like because you cannot use nested play in block like that..

Comment: There is multiple ways to approach this, indeed... the only thing I would say one the code of your question is: please be consistent with yourself, either use the yaml or the ini syntax, but don't mix both as you are doing in here

Comment: yeah I am kinda new to mixing out all the stuff so whats the best way to do this then?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach your issue:

1. Although it is understandable that you tried defining a `hosts: localhost` to run some tasks on the controller, you don't really need this. Using [`delegate_to: localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) and [`run_once: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) on the steps you want to run on your controller is a far better approach.
2. If you really want to go this way (using `hosts: localhost`), for some reason, then you'll need to save the return of your `find`, with [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html?highlight=set_fact) in order to reuse it in other hosts with the help of the global [`hostvars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html?highlight=hostvars#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)

---

### Using delegation

Any task in the play can be delegated to another host. This is quite simple to do and would just use one extra `delegate_to` options on your task:

```
- name: Delegate a find to localhost
  find: 
    path: /test
    file_type: any
  register: localhost_find
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

When doing so, I would advice you to also use `run_once: true`, because, if you delegate the task to another host, there is no need to, let's say run it ten times if you have ten hosts in your host group.

Here is a little example about that

```
---
- hosts: hosts
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Delegate directory creation to localhost
      file: 
        path: /test
        state: directory
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Create directory on hosts
      file:
        path: /test                 
        state: directory

    - name: Delegate file creation to localhost
      file:
        path: /test/localhost.txt                 
        state: touch
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Create file on hosts
      file:
        path: /test/host.txt
        state: touch

    - name: Delegate a find to localhost
      find: 
        path: /test
        file_type: any
      register: localhost_find
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Find in the hosts for comparison
      find:
        path: /test
        file_type: any
      register: host_find

    - name: List /test of localhost
      debug:
        msg: "{{ localhost_find.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

    - name: List /test of host
      debug:    
        msg: "{{ host_find.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"      

    - name: Remove /test folder on localhost
      file:
        path: /test
        state: absent
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Delegate an empty find to localhost
      find:
        path: /test
        file_type: any
      register: empty_find
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Here are our hostnames from the inventory
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: I am the evil host killer
      meta: end_host
      when: empty_find.files | count == 0 and inventory_hostname != 'host1' 

    - debug:
        msg: "I am a sad message, because I will never display :'( But hopefully host1 likes me :')"

    - name: I am the evil playbook killer
      meta: end_play
      when: empty_find.files | count == 0

    - debug:
        msg: "I am a sad message, because I will never display :'( No one likes me..."
```

Where you can see, that, I am skipping the very last debug message by ending the play, when I ended two out of the three hosts I have in my hosts group on the step before.

Output of that playbook:

```
PLAY [hosts] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Delegate directory creation to localhost] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [Create directory on hosts] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [host3]
ok: [host2]
ok: [host1]

TASK [Delegate file creation to localhost] ********************************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [Create file on hosts] ****************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]
changed: [host1]
changed: [host3]

TASK [Delegate a find to localhost] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [Find in the host for comparison] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1]
ok: [host3]
ok: [host2]

TASK [List /test of localhost] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/localhost.txt"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/localhost.txt"
    ]
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/localhost.txt"
    ]
}

TASK [List /test of host] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/host.txt"
    ]
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/host.txt"
    ]
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": [
        "/test/host.txt"
    ]
}

TASK [Remove /test folder on localhost] ***********************************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [Delegate an empty find to localhost] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [host1 -> localhost]

TASK [Here are our hostnames from the inventory] **************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "host3"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "I am a sad message, because I will never display :'( But hopefully host1 likes me :')"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=12   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

In the output, you can easily spot the delegation, as is will output

```
changed: [host1 -> localhost]
```

When a non-delegated task would just go

```
changed: [host1]
```

---

### Using hostvars

I would say the approach is a little bit less state of the art, but could become handy if you would like to delegate on edge cases. I have used it before, so it is not like there is no situation where it could not end up has being the right solution.

Here is the example

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Find in localhost
      find:
        path: /not/existing/folder
        file_type: any
      register: find

    - name: This will register the list under find.files as a variable on the host, making it accessible via hostvars
      set_fact:
        find_result: "{{ find.files }}"

    - meta: end_play
      when: find.files | count == 0

    - debug:
        msg: I am the sanity check message, proving the end_play did happen


- hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Just to show we are not cheating with an empty host group, we display the hosts names
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: To show it is really our empty list and not an empty string or a null variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['find_result'] }}"

    - meta: end_play
      when: "hostvars['localhost']['find_result'] | count == 0"

    - debug:
        msg: I am a first sanity check message, proving the end_play did happen

    - debug:
        msg: I am a second sanity check message, proving the end_play did happen


- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: To show it is really our empty list and not an empty string or a null variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['find_result'] }}"

    - meta: end_play
      when: "hostvars['localhost']['find_result'] | count == 0"

    - debug:
        msg: I am a first sanity check message, proving the end_play did happen

    - debug:
        msg: I am a second sanity check message, proving the end_play did happen
```

Where you can see that, at the beginning of each new tasks group for a host, I just run the `meta` to end the play, based on the variable `find_result` registered out of the `find` result

Here is the output for this one

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find in localhost] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [This will register the list under find.files as a variable on the host, making it accessible via hostvars] *********************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [hosts] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Just to show we are not cheating with an empty host group, we display the hosts names] ******************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "host1"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "host2"
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": "host3"
}

TASK [To show it is really our empty list and not an empty string or a null variable] ************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "msg": []
}

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [To show it is really our empty list and not an empty string or a null variable] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": []
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a block that only triggers your second two tasks after you do your first:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

```
---
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: find the latest file
    find: paths=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/files
          file_type=file
          age=-1m
          age_stamp=mtime
    register: files

  - name: Play 2 & 3 if Play 1 has a file
    block:
      - name: Play 2
        hosts: all
        serial: 5
        tasks:
          - name: copy latest file
            copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data01/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

          - name: copy latest file
            copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data02/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

      - name: Play 3
        hosts: 127.0.0.1
        tasks:
          - name: execute command
            shell: ./data_init --init_file ./goldy.init.qa
    when: files != ""
...
```

Comment: I see.. I am not able to understand blocks properly. Also I need to skip multiple plays in playbook not just tasks in each play. Do you think you can provide an example basis on my above example?

Comment: I am getting some syntax error on this line `- name: Play 2`. Are you sure its valid yml script? Block is confusing me little bit

Comment: so this doesn't work looks like bcoz new Plays nested within others which is not allowed

Comment: Blocks group tasks, not plays.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Variables in hosts value

One trick you can use is set the value of target hosts for the other plays in Play1 this way you can set it to a value that doesn't exist in your inventory (DONOTEXECUTE in the case shown below) the other plays will simply be skipped

```
- name: Play 1
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
      - name: find the latest file
        find: paths=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/files
              file_type=file
              age=-1m
              age_stamp=mtime
        register: files

      - name: Copy file, if found
        copy:
          src: "some stuff here"
          dest: "some other stuff here"
        when: files.files|count > 0
        
     - name: end_plays
        set_fact:
            play2_hosts: DONOTEXECUTE
            play3_hosts: DONOTEXECUTE
        when: files.files|count == 0
        
      - name: continue_plays
        set_fact:
            play2_hosts: all
            play3_hosts: 127.0.0.1
        when: files.files|count > 0

- name: Play 2
  hosts: "{{hostvars['localhost']['play2_hosts']}}"
  serial: 5
  tasks:
      - name: copy latest file
        copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data01/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

      - name: copy latest file
        copy: src=data_init/goldy.init.qa dest=/data02/admin/files/goldy.init.qa owner=golden group=golden

- name: Play 3
  hosts: "{{hostvars['localhost']['play3_hosts']}}"
  tasks:
      - name: execute command
        shell: ./data_init --init_file ./goldy.init.qa
        args:
          chdir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/process/workspace/data_init/
```